# Control sub line width in tkz-collection

Tags: tkz-collection

In `tkz-base` I can control the line width of a grid with the `line width` option as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=4, ymax=2] 
   \tkzGrid[sub,line width=1.5] 
   \tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

However is there also a way to control the line width of the sub grid independently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line width is save in the command `\tkzRatioLineGrid` which is defined as follows.

```
\def\tkzRatioLineGrid{0.75}
```

So you can change this command.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}

\def\tkzRatioLineGrid{0.2} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzInit[xmax=4, ymax=2] 
   \tkzGrid[sub,line width=1.5] 
   \tkzAxeXY
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As @student wrote the changing has no effect. Based on this information I add my File List. (I compiled with pdflatex)

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
tkz-base.sty    2011/06/01 1.16 c tkz-base
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    tikz.sty    2011/06/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.81)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.12)
  pgfrcs.sty    2010/11/07 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.25)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2010/06/30 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.37)
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2007/07/03 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.7)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2007/07/23 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.1)
  pgffor.sty    2010/12/06 v2.10-cvs (rcs-revision 1.20)
 pgfkeys.sty    
 pgfkeys.code.tex
  pgffor.code.tex
    tikz.code.tex
numprint.sty    2008/02/17 v1.38 Print numbers (HH)
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
      fp.sty    1995/04/02
defpattern.sty    1994/10/12
fp-basic.sty    1996/05/13
fp-addons.sty    1995/03/15
 fp-snap.sty    1995/04/05
  fp-exp.sty    1995/04/03
fp-trigo.sty    1995/04/14
  fp-pas.sty    1994/08/29
fp-random.sty    1995/02/23
  fp-eqn.sty    1995/04/03
  fp-upn.sty    1996/10/21
 fp-eval.sty    1995/04/03
tkz-tools-utilities.tex
tkz-tools-arith.tex
tkz-tools-base.tex
tkz-tools-misc.tex
tkz-tools-math.tex
tkz-obj-points.tex
tkz-obj-segments.tex
tkz-obj-marks.tex
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

Comment: Seems to have no effect.

Comment: Yes no effect with value 2

Comment: @student: Please see my update

Comment: Logically you need the last version of texlive with tkz-fct.sty 1.16 and you need tkz-tools-base.tex version 1.17 but this version is not on ctan. You can add  `\makeatletter \edef\tkz@sua@lw{0.4pt}` or  You can download this version from my site http://altermundus.com/SandBox/tkz-tools-base.tex

Comment: @Altermundus: I have `tkz-tools-base` version 1.16 c from CTAN and it works well. Why don't you use a `\ProvidesFileCommand`? In this way the tex-files are listed correct in the `File List`.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't know this command perhaps you want to say  `\ProvidesFile` <space> command ?

Comment: @Altermundus: For my package I have files with the extension `mdf`. Inside I use `\ProvidesFile`. I suggest that you files `tkz-*.tex` also use this command. So the files are listed in the File List with version. `\ProvidesFile{tkz-tools-base.tex}[\filedate~\fileversion~tkz-tools-base]`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel  Thanks yes I need to modify a lot of things. Actually I save all my work with svn and svn-multi to manage correctly all these files. I have a problem with the fact that you don't have a mistake with `tkz-tools-base version 1.16 c` from CTAN. In some cases, `\tkz@sua@lw` gives an error.

Comment: @Altermundus: Maybe you have uploaded a newer version ;-). I don't know. Stefan Kottwitz tested the example too and he has the same result.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I really need to use svn !!

Comment: Thanks, I just replaced my `tkz-tools-base.tex` in my local `texmf`-tree with the version from http://altermundus.com/SandBox/tkz-tools-base.tex, now it works very well!